# Video card compatible with the latest version of Ubuntu Studio

Tags: ubuntu-studio, video-streaming

Is there a list of video cards compatible with the latest version of Ubuntu Studio? I want to upgrade my computer with a brand new video card.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is the best place to check the compatibility of video cards?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40358/which-is-the-best-place-to-check-the-compatibility-of-video-cards)

Answer (score 0):

welcome to AskUbuntu!

The video card requirements for Ubuntu Studio are the same as those for "vanilla" Ubuntu, so anything that can run Ubuntu can also run Ubuntu Studio.

The best resource is to try before you buy (or buy with a reasonable return policy): boot up a live Ubuntu Studio via a USB key and check out performance.

For reference, check out the official [Ubuntu Certified Hardware list](https://ubuntu.com/certified).

Also, look at this (possible repeat) [question and the answers for further discussions of video card compatibility for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40358/which-is-the-best-place-to-check-the-compatibility-of-video-cards).